# A question on models and interpretations of set theories

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Am I right in thinking that a set theory $T$ may interpret a set theory $U$ while it is the case that $T$ has models which are not models of $U\ ?$

In particular, it seems to me that this can happen in case $M$ is a minimal model of $T$.

Comment: When $T$ interprets $U$ then every model of $T$ gives a model of $U$ via the interpretation.  But in the more interesting cases the model of $U$ given by a model of $T$ is not just that model of $T$.  Francois gives examples, and consider also how Peano Arithmetic interprets $ZF$ minus the axiom of infinity -- roughly, a number $n$ is seen as code for the set of $m$ such that the $m$-th binary digit of $n$ is 1.

Comment: I appreciate your notion that if $T$ interprets $U$ then every model of $T$ is a model of $U$ via the interpretation. However, given François' support below, in what sense of "model" may a model of $T$ fail to be a model of $U$?

Comment: No, I said: if $T$ interprets $U$ then a model of $T$ *gives* a model of $U$ but generally *is not* itself a model of $U$.  A model of Peano Arithmetic is not a model of any fragment of ZF, or indeed of any theory in a language with a binary relation (which is why I gave this example).  But it gives a model of ZF minus infinity when you interpret membership in terms of binary expansions.  A model of ZF generally is not a model of ZFC, and is never a model of AFA, but it gives models of each of those in familiar ways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ZFC can interpret ZFC + $V=L$ since the constructible sets in any model of ZFC form a model of ZFC + $V=L$. However, if there is a model of ZFC then there is a model of ZFC + $V\neq L$.

More strikingly, ZFC can interpret [Aczel's AFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom) but since the latter refutes the axiom of foundation, no model of ZFC is a model of AFA.

Comment: Thanks, these are famous and important examples that I failed to think of. The problem I have in mind is connected with a system S of Friedman which is ZF minus extensionality with collection and a weaker power set operation. Friedman shows that S interprets ZF, but it seems to me that a minimal well founded model of S would not be a model of ZF.

Comment: @Frode: That would not be that unusual a situation; one always needs to be careful with interpretations.

Comment: Thanks François! I will ask a question concerning this at the fom list.